# HTML Pop up box on button click

Tags: html, css

I want to open an HTML popup once I click the button. Below is the code I am using, but it is not working. I think there is problem with the way I am passing value to span tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>
<div class="popup" >
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Ankit</span>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML= "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
function myFunction(name,job) {
document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML =
    "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
    var popup =document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I hardcode the value in Span tag, the code works fine and displays the value but it is not accepting the value passed in function.

Comment: i think its given error because you not define name variable you write code in script tag you have to write code in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, i tried it myself and it worked

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('some text')">Click me to toggle the popup!
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"></span>
</div>
<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction(value) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.innerText = value;
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want exactly as your output, but the correct way of doing the code is as below:

```
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">
  <button> Try it </button>
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Ankit </span>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML= "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
function myFunction(name,job) {

    var popup =document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.innerHTML = "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
    popup.classList.toggle("show"); 
}
</script>
```

With respect to this code,

On clicking the "Try it" button, you will get a pop-up as "Welcome Harry Potter, the Wizard. ". The reason being you passed the values "Harry Potter" as name and "Wizard" as job 
`onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')"`

Now, in the function, you declared a variable named popup which stores the value from id "myPopup", which is in this case is "Ankit" right now

In the next line, we are changing the value to be "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".", turning the line to be "Welcome Harry Potter, the Wizard". The value "Ankit" is lost.

`popup.classList.toggle("show");` simply creates the pop-up.

If in case you wish to have "Ankit" as well in the pop-up, you may wish to try this snippet:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">
  <button> Try it </button>
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"> Hi, I am Ankit. </span>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML= "Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
function myFunction(name,job) {

    var popup =document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.innerHTML = popup.innerHTML + " Welcome " + name + ", the " + job + ".";
    popup.classList.toggle("show"); 
}
</script>
```

The popup will now show you as "Hi, I am Ankit. Welcome Harry Potter, the Wizard".

Hope this helps in some way :)

Comment: Thanks Anu, loved you explanation. Really appreciate you efforts.